# form validation error output alignment codeigniter

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

I have this function where I have validation inside a validation

```
 if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload2');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>','</p>');
    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

       print_r('abcd');
       exit();

     }else{
          $this->add_view();
     }


 }else{
      $this->add_view();
 }
```

My only problem is, the second validation does not align on the div. [image]

and doesn't get the color I wanted to

unlike this one

[image]

both of them have the same design

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload', "<p class='text-danger'><i class='  fa fa-times-circle-o' ></i> No file selected</p>");

$this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload2', "<p class='text-danger'>".$this->upload->display_errors()."</p>");
```

Comment: How do you expect help with a style/layout issue when we cannot see the relevant CSS and HTML code?  Also, please do not tag-spam with [tag:jquery] when the question contains no JavaScript.

Comment: don't wrap the message again with the paragraph
$this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload2', $this->upload->display_errors());

Comment: @LuisCardenas yep. i did it. still has the color black tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the display errors return a string wrapped with a paragraph by default,
try this

```
  $this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload2', $this->upload->display_errors('<p class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>', '</p>') );
```

Comment: We cannot even verify the user's CSS rules, so his invalid HTML cannot be pinpointed as the root problem.

Comment: @Sparky i think css has nothing to do with form validations

Comment: @kev_m, the red color you complain is missing comes from CSS.

Comment: @Sparky yes it is from `class = error` and the problem of this is `$this->upload->display_errors()` needs to be inside the `<p class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></p>'`